# Ejb Timer implementation

Tags: jakarta-ee, timer, ejb

How to run particular timeout method in `EJB` using a programmatic timers?

For example:

```
@TimeOut
public void myTmer() {}

@TimeOut
public void myTmer12() {}
```

I only want `mytimer()` method to be fired when timer expires. How can I achieve this?

Comment: First of all, what's the recurrence that you want to impose to your timer?

Answer (score 1):

As an example of a programmatic timer, you may have the following:

```
@LocalBean
@Singleton
@Startup // this timer bean will start on server startup
public class MyTimerBean {

    // injection of the TimerService interface
    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    // on the post construct method one creates the timer
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        // creation of a timer whose first expiration occurs after a specified 
        // duration (1s), and whose subsequent expirations occur after 
        // a specified interval (2s)
        timerService.createTimer(1000, 2000, "MyTimer");
    }

    @Timeout
    public void timeout(Timer timer) {
        System.out.println("Hi from " + timer.getInfo());
    }
}
```

Some points to consider:

- There's other types of timer that can be instantiated (see them [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html));
- Besides the programmatically way of creating the timer, you can also do it automatically, using the `@Schedule` annotation;
- The full documentation can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ejb-basicexamples004.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The code example you provided is not valid, and you will never be in such situation with programmatic timers. Because in that case, a bean can have **at most one** timeout method. As mentionned in the EJB specification, section 18.2.5.1:

> ... If the bean implements the `TimedObject` interface, the `Timeout`
>   annotation or `timeout-method` deployment descriptor element can only be
>   used to specify the `ejbTimeout` method. A bean can have **at most one**
>   timeout method for handling programmatic timers.

Which is, by the way, not the case regarding Automatic timers, as specified in [The Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html#giqmb):

> Automatic timers are created by the EJB container when an enterprise
>   bean that contains methods annotated with the `@Schedule` or `@Schedules`
>   annotations is deployed. An enterprise bean can have **multiple**
>   automatic timeout methods, unlike a programmatic timer, which allows
>   **only one** method annotated with the `@Timeout` annotation in the
>   enterprise bean class.

Comment: if so than if i have 5  programmetic timer defined in each bean than each programmetic timer i defined will execuete timeout method in that respective bean only?

Comment: @AnilAcharya exactely, each programatic timer creation correspond to the single timeout method in that bean. Meanwile, you can create multiple timers in the same bean, but only one timeout method wich will be fired every time a timer expires

Comment: Hi @AnilAcharya if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. There is no obligation to do this.